# SwiftUI Text Shrinks when modified using Bindable Object

Tags: ios, swiftui

**EDIT**

Full code https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/swiftui-getting-started-raywenderlich-com/73445/11?u=prashantkt

I am creating a demo in SwiftUI to match the colors  from https://www.raywenderlich.com/3715234-swiftui-getting-started

I have done some experiments on that demo , Please let me know if you need more code or information :)

This is how looks like on first run

[image]

On Match me button tapped I compute the score

and show alert and rest the slider value,

```
 Button(action: {
         self.score = self.computeScore()

        self.resetTheColor()

        self.needToShoWAlert = true


      }) {
            Text("Match me")
      }

    func resetTheColor () {
        rTarget  = Double.random(in: 0..<1)
        gTarget = Double.random(in: 0..<1)
        bTarget = Double.random(in: 0..<1)

        sliderBinder.reset()
    }
```

And Here is sliderBinder class

```
class SliderBindable:BindableObject {

    var r:Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            didChange.send((r,g,b))
        }
    }
    var g:Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            didChange.send((r,g,b))

        }
    }
    var b:Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            didChange.send((r,g,b))

        }
    }

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<(r:Double,g:Double,b:Double),Never>()



    func reset() {
        r = 0
        g = 0
        b = 0
    }


}
```

Label shrinks when rest the r,g,b value

see the screen shot

[image]

Comment: Can you please add full Code so we can test it?

Comment: @KetanOdedra https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/swiftui-getting-started-raywenderlich-com/73445/11?u=prashantkt